# Where can I walk with an eiruv techumin?

Tags: shabbat, eruv-techumin

How does an eiruv techumin work (assuming I live in a city):

1) I put my eiruv within 2000 amos of my house and I can walk throughout the city, and in 2000 amos in any direction from my eiruv

2) I put my eiruv within 2000 amos of my house and I can only walk within 2000 amos of my eiruv

3) I put my eiruv within 2000 amos of the edge of the city that I live in and I can walk throughout the city and 2000 amos in any direction from the eiruv

4) I put my eiruv within 2000 amos of the edge of the city that I live in and I can only walk within 2000 amos of my eiruv (I realize that this one doesn’t make sense- you wouldn’t be able to leave your house)

5) other?

Sourced answer please!

Comment: A person’s place is defined as the four amos that surround him. If he is in an inhabited city, the entire city is considered to be his place, and his calculations begin when he leaves the city. In addition, if he is standing in a fenced in area which was enclosed for residential purposes (even if it is no longer inhabited), or, in an enclosed area which was not enclosed for residential purposes, but has an area of a sasssayim or less, the entire enclosed area is considered to be his place.

[שו"ע שצו, א-ב, ומשנ"ב ב, יא, יב ו־יג; ביאורים ומוספים דרשו, 1 ו־8 - via daf hayomi email 7/8/19]

Comment: I'm a little confused how detailed you want an answer to be, but the basic rule is if you put an Eruv Techumin somewhere, you calculate your Techum as if you were living at the food when Shabbat starts instead of wherever you happen to be standing then. Then all the normal rules of cities and 2000 Amot apply. I don't know what you mean by "assuming I live in a city"

Answer (score 1):

The details are explained in [OC 408](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.408.1?with=all&lang=bi). A person has 2000 amos in any direction outside of his own 4 amos of personal space in which he may walk on Shabbos. A person who is located in a city at the beginning of Shabbos may count that entire city as if it's all his 4 amos, but a city that he did not start in may not be counted as within 4 amos.

Establishing an eruv techumim sets that location as his starting place for Shabbos. That's really all you need to know. After that, just apply the normal rules of techum surrounding the place where the eruv was placed.

So if the eruv is outside of a city, he may not leave the 2000 amos surrounding that location, even if part of his city is outside that area. So suggestion #4 is correct. If you place an eruv within your city, it as the same as if you didn't place one at all. You may walk throughout the city and 2000 amos from the edges.

Comment: Note that your first line of your last paragraph is only according the the Mechaber. The Rama rules that one can traverse the entire city as long as part of it is in the Trchum.

Comment: So if I place my eiruv techumin 1000 amos west of the edge of the city, and I live more than 1000 amos away from the western edge of the city, I can’t leave my house (according to the first sentence in the last paragraph)?

Comment: @LoAni an Eruv (of any kind) only takes effect if you can access it at the start of Shabbat. If you put an Eruv Tavshillin in a locked electronic box with no way to access it on Yom Tov, it doesn't work and you can't cook. So too if a resident of London puts an Eruv Techumin in San Francisco, it doesn't do anything and his Techum is still London.

Comment: Thanks @DoubleAA and Daniel. I assume according to the Rema (that salmononious2 quoted) I can make an eiruv techumin anywhere within 2000 amos of the city, even if my house is not within 2000 amos of the eiruv? Daniel- Whether that’s correct or not, please edit the Rema into the answer so that it is complete and doesn’t confuse other users